# Camel FTP Fails to retrieve files based on the include filter

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I am using Apache camel 2.13.2 and am trying to connect to an FTP to retrieve files based on the file expression given in the include parameter. I can see that there are files in the folder in the ftp account, but camel doesn't pull the files.  I can see in the log that the connection is successful, but the exchange is returned as null.  The same code works for other ftp accounts.  Could someone help to understand on where I am doing wrong, and things that I could try to get this fixed?

```
ftp://XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXX:21/testfolder/testfold/test?password=RAW(XXXXXXX)&binary=true&pollStrategy=#xxxFTPPollingConsumerPollStrategy&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&delay=15000&maxMessagesPerPoll=30&stepwise=false&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true&idempotent=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}-${file:modified}&readLock=changed&include=.*
```

Comment: Mind that `include` is regular expression based, so make sure what you use would match what Java regular expression would match.

Comment: The same include regular expression works for other ftp's. Even if I remove the include filter completely, it doesn't pull the files from the folder.

Comment: @Ravi what do you mean with "The same code works for other ftp accounts"? That the same camel route works with other credentials?

Comment: No we use the same code for connecting to different external ftp's.  So the same code is working with some clients and not with others.

Answer (score 3):

first try without any filters to see if it is the problem.

In any case, depending on the server and client firewalls and linux vs windows encoding (for the file transfer) you should give a try to the following URI parameters:

```
binary=true
passiveMode=true
```

most of the times with the default **passiveMode** camel wont list any file and file transfer may fail with an `ArrayOutOfBounds` error.

To double check set the logging level of camel to debug and to trace for the ftp component:

```
logging.level.org.apache.camel=DEBUG
logging.level.org.apache.camel.component=TRACE
```

without **passiveMode=true** you will likely notice that the list file doesn't find any file.

more info about the FTP passive mode can be found [here](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)